# Style differences between wordpress.com and hosted wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, wordpress.com

I'm trying to understand where the style differences are coming from between my hosted installation of Wordpress with the exact theme installed on my Wordpress.com account. I'm migrating my blog and they are wildly different for some reason.

[Irrelevant, experimentation]

What seems to be going on? I've tried to check the CSS & JS but those have been unhelpful.

Comment: For now I'm going to continue using wordpress.com as there's still some quirky errors with CSS and it's going to take a long time to make sure both are adjusted appropriately.

Comment: I'm requesting to close/delete this answer because I'm experimenting and the links to help will be irrelevant

Comment: You shouldn't delete this. Obviously, you found this somewhat helpful, and there may very well in fact be others who stumble upon this content who have the same questions regarding migration from Wordpress.com to Wordpress.org. The goal of Stackoverflow isn't just to help you, but to leave a string of breadcrumbs behind that can help others find their way for years to come.

Comment: Point taken, just wondering if the question still had the appropriate context to be useful

Comment: If not, the community would have closed it already. We're pretty quick about closing questions that are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML and CSS for the two sites are drastically different. Additionally, the wordpress.com site is also importing a lot more resources than your .org site.  If you look in your NET tab in your Chrome debugger, you can also see that there are other CSS files being loaded in the .com site that may be overriding or conflicting with some of the other styles.

You'll need to make sure that you're importing all of the CSS, images, and JavaScript from the original site into the new site; otherwise, there will be differences.